Difference between quantum coherence and quantum superposition
Pretty much as the title suggests, is there any concrete difference between the two phenomena? Or is it stemming from using different words in different areas of quantum mechanics, because as I understand coherence is more used in quantum optics aspect.

There's a nomenclature collision between a "coherent state," which are a few very particular classes of states for oscillators, spin systems, and things that look like them; and "coherence" vs. "decoherence", which is mostly equivalent to "pure state" vs. "mixed state."
The most common use of "coherent state" is for a state of the quantum harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian $H = \omega ( a^\dagger a + 1/2)$  which is an eigenstate of the annihilation operator $a$.  If you think this through, you see that this is equivalent to the state being, in a sense, "maximally classical," which means that it saturates the Heisenberg uncertainty principle for position and momentum in a way which can be said to be "symmetric" in those two observables.  I'm using scare quotes because you should just read about them in any QM text or in the many SE answers on them.
The infinite-dimensional Hilbert space of a QHO is that of a 0-dimensional boson.  Analogously, we can define "fermionic coherent states," which are the eigenstates of the fermionic annihilation operator on the two-dimensional fermionic Hilbert space.  You can also define "spin coherent states" on a $2S+1$-dimensional spin Hilbert space, which are maximally classical in that they maximize the norm of the expectation value of the vector spin operator, $|\langle \hat{\vec{S}} \rangle | = S$.  This seems kind of different to the other two cases, but it shares a lot of important algebraic properties, most importantly that the coherent states (of any of these kinds) form a convenient overcomplete basis of their Hilbert spaces.  This is nice for defining path integrals in field theory in a symmetrical way that doesn't make you pick a single (orthonormal) basis.  A good reference on all of this in a condensed matter context is Altland's Condensed Matter Field Theory.
The other usage of "coherent" refers to a pure state, instead of a mixed state.  People say things like "$|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$ is a coherent superposition", which is exactly the same as saying "... is a quantum superposition."  This implies that there exists an incoherent superposition which is something like $\rho = p |0 \rangle \langle 0 | + (1-p) |1 \rangle\langle 1|$, but people don't really usually call it that.  It is definitely said, though, that the off-diagonal terms in a density matrix are the "coherences," and that a pure state is "maximally coherent."  "Decoherence" is the process of a system interacting with and thus entangling itself with its environment, which leads to it being in a mixed(/"decohered") state if you forget the environment's full quantum state.  Schlosshauer's Decoherence and the Quantum-to-Classical Transition is a good reference on this, and its introduction has a brief history on when people started calling it that.
I should note that I don't know much about quantum optics, but I'm quite sure that they use "coherent state" mostly in the bosonic E+M field sense.  I wouldn't be surprised if they also used the "decoherence" sense of the word, too.  Someone who knows should correct me.

Thank you, so I guess theres no key difference as you said.
